# How to use git submodule in Jenkins file to create two different docker build

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I have one git repo let's say `git@github.com:example/example.git` with one Dockerfile. Inside the same repo there is one more repo (submodule) `git@github.com:example/abc.git` with the Second Dockerfile.

So I want to create a Single Jenkinsfile which can create DockerImages using Dockerfile from both the repos.

But I am only able to create one DockerImage from the main repo, From the submodule repo there is an error saying `Path not found`.

My Jenkins file looks like this:

```
stage('Clone Repo'){
    node('master'){
      cleanWs()
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/$GIT_BRANCH']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'git@github.com:example/example.git']]])
    }
  }

  stage('Build Docker Image for **First Image**') {
    node('master'){
      sh "\$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)"
      GIT_COMMIT_ID = sh (
        script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%H',
        returnStdout: true
      ).trim()
      TIMESTAMP = sh (
        script: 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S',
        returnStdout: true
      ).trim()
      echo "Git commit id: ${GIT_COMMIT_ID}"
      IMAGETAG="${GIT_COMMIT_ID}-${TIMESTAMP}-${NAME_SPACE}"
      sh "sudo docker build -t ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${ECR_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGETAG} ."    # First Dockerfile is in main repo folder
          sh "sudo docker push ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${ECR_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGETAG}"
    }
  }

  stage('Build Docker **Second Image**') {
    node('master'){
      sh "\$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2)"
      GIT_COMMIT_ID = sh (
        script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%H',
        returnStdout: true
      ).trim()
      TIMESTAMP = sh (
        script: 'date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S',
        returnStdout: true
      ).trim()
      echo "Git commit id: ${GIT_COMMIT_ID}"
      IMAGETAG="${GIT_COMMIT_ID}-${NAME_SPACE}-ad-frontend-${TIMESTAMP}"
          sh "sudo docker build -t ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${ECR_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGETAG} submodule/Dockerfile"  # second Dockerfile is in submodule folder
          sh "sudo docker push ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/${ECR_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGETAG}"
    }
  }
```

Comment: The last argument to `docker build` is a directory name, not the Dockerfile name, so just try `submodule` there.  (You might try running these `docker` commands by hand outside of Jenkins, and also look into the integration described in [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) in the Jenkins documentation.)

Comment: that does not work, same error.

Comment: find the answer :) thanks